# Tomcat connecting to MariaDB using TLS throws javax.naming.NamingException; command line connection works properly

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 7 on web host `foo` connecting to MariaDB 5.5.56 on database host `bar`, using user `bob`.  All systems are running CentOS 7.  Initially this connection used password based authentication.

Now there is a requirement to encrypt the connection with TLS.  I have a certificate and key file for each host foo and bar.  I have configured MariaDB to use these; the `my.cnf` file on the database host contains these relevant lines:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/pki/ca.crt
ssl-cert=/etc/pki/bar.crt
ssl-key=/etc/pki/bar.key
```

I have confirmed within MariaDB that TLS is enabled.  I have also confirmed that all remote connections have `ssl_type` set to `X509`.

I am able to connect to the database on the command line from the web host:

user@foo > `mysql -h bar -u bob -p --ssl-ca=/etc/pki/ca.crt --ssl-key=/etc/pki/foo.key --ssl-cert=/etc/pki/foo.crt`

So far, this proves that the certificates are correct, and that `bob` has access to the database.

The Tomcat config `server.xml` contains this connector:

```
    <Connector port="443"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="500"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/etc/pki/foo.jks"
               keystorePass="abcde"
               truststoreFile="/etc/pki/trust"
               truststorePass="zzgo"
               clientAuth="false"
               sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Using keytool, I have verified that the passwords match the store files.  (Of course, the passwords shown here are fake.)

I have added the proper `<security-constraint>` to Tomcat's `web.xml`.

According to all my research, these settings should enable Tomcat to connect to MariaDB using these certs and store files.  However, when connecting to a servlet Data that communicates with the database, the log shows exceptions like this:

```
    SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Data
    javax.naming.NamingException: Access denied for user 'bob'@'foo' (using password: YES)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:865)
            ...
            at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
            at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:137)
            ...
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
           ... and so on
```

The error indicates that something in the database connection is incorrect; whether it's a Tomcat setting, the stores, or something else is more than I have been able to determine.

#### Edit 1

I have confirmed that the fingerprint of `foo.crt` matches the fingerprint of the certificate stored in `foo.jks`.

#### Edit 2

I made a test application using the same `Properties` entries.  The test app DOES connect using TLS.  Therefore, as suggested, the issue resides somewhere in the JDBC

As far as I can tell, there's only one difference:  The real app converts the `Properties` object to a `PoolConfiguration` object using `DataSourceFactory.parsePoolProperties()`.  Then I try to debug this using `poolProperties.getConnectionProperties()`, but the resulting string is `null`.  I'm trying to find other ways to debug the pool properties.

Comment: I don't think the `Connector` configuration nor the security-constraints are relevant to solving your problem. These relate to securing your connection to Tomcat over HTTPS and ensuring users who lack permissions don't have access to certain pages. They don't do anything relating to securing Tomcat's connection to MySQL.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: How can I check that the Tomcat-MariaDB connection is properly secured (or what isn't properly securing it)?

Comment: `Access denied for user 'bob'@'foo' (using password: YES)`: this message comes from MariaDB. It is proof that the TCP and TLS parts are working perfectly. The problem here is the username or password.

Comment: @user207421: As I said in the question, with the TLS key and certs specified on the command line, the user, host, and password successfully connect to the database.  You are correct in that the problem lies somewhere in authentication, just not in that part.

Comment: Just not in what part? The fact that you got an error code back from the database server indicates that the TLS part is working perfectly. No two ways about it.

Comment: @user207421: And the fact that I was able to log in to the database server on the command line with the TLS certs indicates that the username/password part is also working perfectly.  So I suppose my question is, what lies between the two?

Comment: Did you grant access, e.g. with `GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES ON *.* TO 'bob'@'foo' IDENTIFIED BY password`?

Comment: And note that "a requirement to encrypt the connection" doesn't mean you have to use a client certificate.

Comment: And since your issue is mainly a matter of JDBC configuration, you could start by writing a very simple command-line program (just a few lines) to test the JDBC connection. Forget about Tomcat and its `Connector` configuration (they are totally irrelevant here).

Comment: @Oliver: Given the `my.cnf` entries presently on the database server, what changes do I need to make to use client certificate authentication?  Also, if I change the users to use `SSL` instead of `X509`, the Java servlets still fail to connect.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: My version of MariaDB uses `ssl_type` of `ANY`.  I have confirmed that this still works on the command line but not in the Java servlet.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht: If that was a problem, should the MySQL command line connection also fail?

Comment: @StephanSchlecht: I juct checked `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'bob'@'%'`.  The first line is `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bob'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '_hashed-value_' REQUIRE SSL`

Comment: *"what changes do I need"* As I said, this is JDBC configuration, which means you should read the documentation of your JDBC driver.

Comment: @Olivier I've been working on that.  I've found that the JDBC driver needs to be explicitly told to use TLS (`useSSL=true`).  I've made updates in Java and in `server.xml` to pass that -- but it's not getting to the runtime.

Comment: @Oliver: I made a test Java application and connected using `DriverManager`.  It worked as a standalone app and also within the actual code.  I haven't gotten `DataSource` to compile as a standalone app yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are advised to add parameters in JDBC

```sh
useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=true&requireSSL=true
```